# JS - Why does await not work in class

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to wait some time inside a function of a class. I tried to adapt [Jonas W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087233/when-does-requestanimationframe-fire/50087267#50087267) answer: https://jsfiddle.net/5wk2cohe/

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

class K {
  run(n) {
    (async function() {
      document.body.textContent = n;
      await sleep(1000);
    })();
  }
}

var v = new K();
for (let n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
  v.run(n);
}
```

But the counts prompts immediately 3. If I run https://jsfiddle.net/tctxcn9o/
I see a counter as excepted:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

 (async function() {
   for(let n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
     document.body.textContent = n;
     await sleep(1000);
   }
})();
```

What I am doing wrong?

**[Update] Some background:** In my hometown a very old programm called JavaKara is very popular to help students at the high school to lern how to code:

[image: JavaKara]

To see how the ladybug moves is very helpful for understanding and finding your error. So I am trying to wait some time after each step of the ladybug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [El Aoutar Hamza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088263/2762095) said, you're creating 4 async tasks where every task is run instantly. In order to delay the next task, you need to use `await` inside the loop and make the `run` function return a Promise, something like this:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

class K {
  async run(n) {
    document.body.textContent = n;
    await sleep(1000);
  }
}

(async function() {
  var v = new K();
  for (let n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    await v.run(n);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thats amasing! Do you see a way that I only have to write "v.run(n);" and not "await v.run(n);"? The reason is that I want to use my programm to help my students to make their first steps in programming. So v.run is mutch more understandable then "await v.run.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are creating 4 `async` functions that are not related to each other, so none of them has to wait for the other.

While in your second example, you are creating 1 `async` function, where the `await` expression causes the `async` function execution to pause until the promise `sleep` is fulfilled.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Do you have any idea how I could realize to wait inside the class?

Comment: This has nothing to do with using classes, you can change your first example to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ch3z8n4u/) and you will end up seeing the same result.

What you can do is moving the loop inside your async function, or use [promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)